# batch rename files with different file extensions to 1 extension

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename

I'm recently new to batch scripting. I need to rename a few thousand files, each one having a different file extension to a single common extension. The files come off a machine like so:

```
1.2.840.113619.2.131.3171610912.1353091118.893703
```

which windows tells me is a type "893703" file because of the fullstop(.) position.

So I need to turn this example:

```
1.2.840.113619.2.131.3171610912.1353091118.893703
1.2.840.113619.2.131.3171610912.1353091118.907596
1.2.840.113619.2.131.3171610912.1353091118.920723
1.2.840.113619.2.131.3171610912.1353091118.932988
1.2.840.113619.2.131.3171610912.1353091118.945443
```

into this

```
1.2.840.113619.2.131.3171610912.1353091118.893703.IMA
1.2.840.113619.2.131.3171610912.1353091118.907596.IMA
1.2.840.113619.2.131.3171610912.1353091118.920723.IMA
1.2.840.113619.2.131.3171610912.1353091118.932988.IMA
1.2.840.113619.2.131.3171610912.1353091118.945443.IMA
```

I can edit the text string before the extension, and change a series of the same extension, but I'm not sure how to deal with files of different extensions.

I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following on the command line:

```
ren *.* *.*.IMA
```